# Basic authentication in Fuse 7.5

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am using Redhat Fuse 7.5 version. I have implemented REST DSL using servlet component as below.

```
restConfiguration()
        .component("servlet")
        .host("0.0.0.0")
        .port("9999")
        .scheme("http")
        .contextPath("/xyz/rest")
        .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
        .skipBindingOnErrorCode(false)
        .enableCORS(true);

rest("/api")
          .get("/checkServiceAvailabilty")
          .outType(MyAppResponse.class)
          .route()
          .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getOut().setBody(new MyAppResponse(RESPONSE_CODE_200,RESPONSE_DESC_SUCCESS));
                }
            }).endRest();
```

My servlet configuration in Blueprint.xml

```
<reference id="httpService" interface="org.osgi.service.http.HttpService"/>
  <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.osgi.OsgiServletRegisterer"
        init-method="register"
        destroy-method="unregister">
    <property name="alias" value="/ftsis/rest"/>
    <property name="httpService" ref="httpService"/>
    <property name="servlet" ref="camelServlet"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="camelServlet" class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet"/>
```

Can someone please give me some pointers for implementing Basic Authentication in Fuse 7. In Fuse 7 default HTTP server is Undertow.

Comment: If you use `restConfiguration().host("0.0.0.0").port("9999")`, you set up your own http server and should take care of everything because you don't use managed http server (one coming from Fuse itself).

Comment: Oh its not really correct when you use servlet, then it uses the servlet as-is. The host and port are for documentation purposes, where you can enter the port number of the servlet engine that its using (its maybe 8181 on karaf, and 8080 on tomcat etc).

Comment: And for basic auth, then you set this up via the servlet